# Sum the values in specific columns of a pandas pivot table with multi index

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, multi-index

I have created a pivot table with multiple index as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Customer':['Tom Ford','Susan Mock','Tom Ford','Tom Ford','Donale Fucci','Jo Watthanaram'],
                           'Merchant':['Merchant_A','Merchant_A','Merchant_B','Merchant_A' ,'Merchant_B','Merchant_C'],
                           'Type' : ["Type A","Type A", "Type A", "Type A", "Type A", "Type B"],
                           'Date':['20/09/2021  17:45:27','21/09/2021  18:59:24','22/10/2021  20:42:03','25/10/2021  20:42:03','23/10/2021  20:42:03','20/11/2021  20:42:03'],
                           'Sales':[1000,2000,3000,8000,4000,5000],
                            })

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df1['Date_onlyMonth'] = df1['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%b')

pivot_1 = pd.pivot_table(df1,index=['Customer','Merchant'],columns=['Type','Date_onlyMonth'],values=["Sales"],aggfunc=[np.sum, len])
pivot_1 = pivot_1.reindex(level='Date_onlyMonth',columns=['2021-Sep','2021-Oct','2021-Nov']).reindex()
```

My pivot table is like this

```
    print(pivot_1)
                               sum                        len                  
                             Sales                      Sales                  
Type                        Type A            Type B   Type A            Type B
Date_onlyMonth            2021-Sep 2021-Oct 2021-Nov 2021-Sep 2021-Oct 2021-Nov
Customer       Merchant                                                        
Donale Fucci   Merchant_B      NaN   4000.0      NaN      NaN      1.0      NaN
Jo Watthanaram Merchant_C      NaN      NaN   5000.0      NaN      NaN      1.0
Susan Mock     Merchant_A   2000.0      NaN      NaN      1.0      NaN      NaN
Tom Ford       Merchant_A   1000.0   8000.0      NaN      1.0      1.0      NaN
               Merchant_B      NaN   3000.0      NaN      NaN      1.0      NaN
```

I want to create subtotals columnar-wise for "Type A"
I tried as shown below scripts, but nothing worked. Appreciate it if someone can help with this.

```
pivot_1[:,'Type A Total'] = pivot_1.loc[:,['2021-Sep','2021-Oct']].sum(axis=1) # This gives an error "TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'"
pivot_1[:,'Type A Total'] = pivot_1.loc[:,['Type']].sum(axis=1)  # This gives an error "TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'"
 
pivot_1['Type A Total'] = pivot_1[['2021-Sep','2021-Oct']].sum(axis=1) # This gives an error "KeyError: "['2021-Sep' '2021-Oct'] not in index"'"
pivot_1['Type A Total'] = pivot_1[['Type A']].sum(axis=1) # This gives an error "KeyError: "['Type A'] not in index""
pivot_1['Type A Total'] = pivot_1[['Type']].sum(axis=1)  # This gives an error "KeyError: "['Type'] not in index""
 
pivot_1['Type A Total'] = pivot_1[:2].sum(axis=1)  # This gives wrong total
pivot_1.loc[:,'Type A Total'] = pivot_1.sum(['2021-Sep','2021-Oct'], axis=1) # This gives "TypeError: stat_func() got multiple values for argument 'axis'"
```

My expected pivot table is like this

```
    print(pivot_1)
                               sum                        len                  Type A Total
                             Sales                      Sales                  
Type                        Type A            Type B   Type A            Type B
Date_onlyMonth            2021-Sep 2021-Oct 2021-Nov 2021-Sep 2021-Oct 2021-Nov
Customer       Merchant                                                        
Donale Fucci   Merchant_B      NaN   4000.0      NaN      NaN      1.0      NaN   4000.0
Jo Watthanaram Merchant_C      NaN      NaN   5000.0      NaN      NaN      1.0      NaN
Susan Mock     Merchant_A   2000.0      NaN      NaN      1.0      NaN      NaN   2000.0
Tom Ford       Merchant_A   1000.0   8000.0      NaN      1.0      1.0      NaN   9000.0
               Merchant_B      NaN   3000.0      NaN      NaN      1.0      NaN   3000.0
```

Comment: `pivot_1[("sum", "Sales", "Type A")].sum(1)`?

Comment: Thanks, @HenryYik, I prefer to get the result into a new column within the same data-frame.

Comment: Then just assign it to a new column.

Comment: This snippet worked
 
`pivot_1['Type A Total'] = pivot_1[("sum", "Sales", "Type A")].sum(axis=1)`